# External Monitor attached with iPad shows black padding

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad

I have used code from link below to enable external display for my iPad App.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/windows_and_screens/displaying_content_on_a_connected_screen

The code works, (i.e. we can see the viewcontroller rendered on external display). However there is a black padding from all sides which I am not able to figure out. I need to make it a full screen experience.

On the same iPad, Photos app when attached on external monitor shows full screen photos.

Any help would be appreciated.

PS. we have tried it with three different monitors. Full HD and 4K as well.

[image]

Comment: Have you set `overscanCompensation` on your second screen to `.none`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `overscanCompensation` property on your second `UIScreen` instance to `.none`